# Web Site with daily updates, is recommended with Angular?

Tags: angular, single-page-application

I'm starting in the Angular development with Nodejs, and I'm worried about this question:

For sites that require constant content updates, such as a news portal or an e-commerce, having Build in every app whenever it has a small change in the site, it's horrible. What would be the solution to this?

or is there no solution and is it best to go to Multi-Pages?

Comment: This sound like you have designed things non-ideally. Lots of dynmaic news type sites use these technologies. Maybe supply a [mcve] and show what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your question is not clear enough, but I will try to help:

I believe you are not limited with Angular as long as you don't plan to write pure static html for your news. You would need a backend in the language of your choice (maybe nodejs) that would store your news in a database, and you would retrieve them with Angular with 'ajax' requests. Updates of the angular app in that case would then be less frequent. I don't think however that building your app once you made a change should be an issue, you could compile it automatically on every git push for instance on your prod server.